# Regression Modelling with reduced degrees of freedom

Tags: r, regression

I've done a bit of data analysis and regression modeling, but I'm not a statistician by trade, so please be kind.

I have a complex deterministic model that takes (currently) 5 inputs with 2 parameters (probability and profit) to calculate an overall profit.

I have a large pool of possible inputs and evnew with just 5 decisions I am faced with trillions of comibinations. I want to refine tis model to 10-50 decisions so I'm looking for a good way of detremining the best actions and removeing the rest.

With a bit of logical deduction I was able to create a score with with a resonable correlation (>0.8) to the final profit. However some of the very best results are outliers in my resulting scatterplot, so I'm looking for a better model.

I've used R's `lm` to create much better fit with all 10 inputs, however this means I have a different

I've used R to refine the model like.

```
lm(formula = profit ~
   prob1+prob2+prob3+...+profit4+profit5, 
   data = mydata)
```

The fit I get is far better but this has some issues:

- Rather than having a coefficient for each input, I'd like these classed into categories (probabilities/profits), so that while I'll pass all 10 inputs, I just get a coeficicent for probabilities and one for profits, so that I can classify the inputs independent of their place in the overall model.
- The profit is critical for low probability inputs, but it's almost irrelevant when the probability is very high. I don't believe a linear model can reflect this.
- Finally (and if possible) I would like my model to be relatively straightforward and easily portable into another language.

Can you recommend any solution that might be suitable for these requirements?